# Ftp Client-Server, my 'cd ..' command messes up my 'pwd' command

Tags: ftp, server, client, cd, pwd

On my client-side, if I cd into a directory and pwd it, it'll show me the correct pwd. (ftp> means client-side)

```
ftp> cd adam
ftp> pwd
remote working directory: amlodoz1/p1/adam
```

But if I then 'cd ..' out of it, and hit pwd, it gives me this:

```
ftp> cd ..
ftp> pwd
remote working directory: amlodoz1/p1/adam/..
```

Obviously, pwd should return `amlodoz1/p1/` but it just likes to append whatever characters I cd into to the pathname.

My implementation for 'cd' and 'pwd' are here.

```
    public void cd(String dirName) throws IOException{
            System.out.println("Changing directory to '" + dirName + "'");
            File dir = new File(dirName);
            System.setProperty("user.dir", dir.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public void pwd() throws IOException{
            String pwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.out.println("Remote working directory: " + pwd);
    }
```

I was thinking about writing an if clause for 'cd ..' but I don't know what I would set the "user.dir" to in the setProperty function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just realized there was a `.getParent()` method, so writing out worked.

```
    public void cd(String dirName) throws IOException{
            System.out.println("Changing directory to '" + dirName + "'");
            if(dirName.equals("..")){
                    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                    System.setProperty("user.dir", dir.getAbsoluteFile().getParent());
            }
            else{
                    File dir = new File(dirName);
                    System.setProperty("user.dir", dir.getAbsolutePath());
            }

    }
```